# c# foreach statement with a add is super slow for me?

Tags: c#, .net

Wonder if anyone could explain what is going on with this weird little optimisation in our draw code. We replaced the first little bit of code with the second and got a huge speed increase (4400 tick -> 15 ticks using stopwatch class)

```
// Add all the visible sprites to the list
m_renderOrder.Clear();
foreach (CSpriteInternalData sprite in m_InternalData)
{
    if (!sprite.m_bRender) continue;
    m_renderOrder.Add(sprite);
}
```

Replaced with...

```
// Add all the visible sprites to the list
m_renderOrder.Clear();
renderOrderCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < m_numSprites; i++ )
{
    if (m_InternalData[i].m_bRender)
        m_renderOrder[renderOrderCount++] = m_InternalData[i];
}
```

I looks to be the simplest little change, for such a huge increase in speed. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is CSpriteInternalData a `struct` by any chance? And if so, how big? The second piece of code can be made faster by using a variable to keep a copy of the `m_InternalData` indexed item, instead of indexing it twice.

Comment: Is m_InternalData a struct perhaps?

Comment: What is `CSpriteInternalData`? What type is `m_InternalData`? What type is `m_renderOrder`?

Comment: how did you measure the difference? the indexing will (usually) be faster but not by a magnitude of 30 which suggest that some of the difference could be from the benchmarking more than the actual difference in the code or simply that `m_numSprites < m_InternalDat.Count()`

Comment: What if you use `m_renderOrder.Add` inside the second `for` loop instead of accessing by indexer?

Comment: The complete lack of response from the OP is ruining my interest in this question...

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth, not very patient, are you? The question was asked only 12 minutes ago... The OP is new here, so he doesn't know how fast it is to get an answer on SO ;)

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I am perfectly patient considering the OP will be receiving notifications about feedback. But it depends if you subscribe to the fire and forget mantra of regular forums. For SO, I don't. The average response is extremely quick.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth, as I said, the OP is new here; he doesn't know that yet.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Fair enough, but I stand by my comment. I tend to frequently visit questions I ask on any forum in case questions are asked, so I find it puzzling when others don't. At the end of the day, you are requesting free help, some investment from the other side would be helpful - the first three questions still remain unanswered and are pertinent to the final explanation.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, busy day at work. m_InternalData was both a list and a vector, both yealded the same result.

Comment: Also, as I said I had a fix so didn't really need a quick fix, this was mostly because I wanted to know why this was so I didn't do the same thing again. but I can happily just not use the foreach loop.

Answer (score 3):

If `CSpriteInternalData` is a `struct`, i.e. a value type, each time when you assign a value of that type to a variable, a copy is done.

```
MyStruct a = new MyStruct(50);
MyStruct b = a; //a is copied to b;
a.Value = 10;
Console.WriteLine(b.Value); //still 10, has a separate copy of value
```

If structs are small and portable, that is not much of a problem, but if the structs are large, they can get slow. `Foreach` creates a variable that is repeatedly assigned a value from the collection, so if `CSpriteInternalData` is a `struct`, each one is in turn copied to the `sprite` variable, and that could take time.

Also, the line when you `Add` the item to the `m_renderOrder` collection, invokes another copy of the structure, but I guess only a few of them have the `m_bRender` flag set, so that one does not take too much time.

If that is the cause of the slowdown / speedup I would wholeheartedly recommend that you change `CSpriteInternalData` to a class, that would use reference behavior, and just copy references around, instead of whole copies.

Comment: Indeed, then a copy is done when the enumerator yields, and another copy is done adding it to the other collection.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth The second copy happens in both scenarios, that's why I didn't mention it (but I will)

Comment: Fair enough, the main point being that the use of a `struct` in `foreach` which has the enumerator state machine in the background is potentially more noticeable because of extra copy actions done by the enumerator. Where as the second sample on has what looks like 2 copy actions. However, I would expect this cost to be linear.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I would also expect that List<large_struct> performs worse that List<class> because of the larger memory required when the List extends it's capacity.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, good point. However in this case it looks like the list shouldn't resize otherwise the second index-only solution would go out of bounds (so I assume the list is already the correct size).

Comment: CSpriteInternalData is already a class. Would have shown this in the code snippet but with the C at the front, I thought it was implied.

Comment: @DrewO'Malley: can you show it's definition? Also, how was the performance testing done?

Answer (score 0):

foreach always creates an instance of an enumerator that is returned by GetEnumerator method and that enumerator also keeps state throughout the life cycle of the foreach loop. 
It then repeatedly calls for the Next() object on the enumerator and runs your code for each object it returns.

You can create you own emulator in case. But better to user for loop instead when execution time matters.

Comment: How do you know how the `Enumerator` and `indexer` are implemented?

Comment: http://www.abhisheksur.com/2011/01/internals-of-loops-while-for-and.html you can refer to the link for detailed study !!

Comment: The linked article doesn't tell me what the type of `m_InternalData` is so, its generalisations about implementations may or may not apply.

Comment: When you are using for each loop, it is obvious that NEXT() is gonna call the next object. For this operation emulator will be used. What approach do you see in here ?

Comment: Either way, can you do a `for` loop on an `Enumerable.Range`, I think not, so its analysis is flawed, however well intentioned. I think you'll find the CIL of an empty loop can be optimized to nothing.

Comment: I agree to your arguments. But isn't it when for each loop executes, it always got for emulator call ?

Comment: You can't know how `Enumerator.Next` is implemented with knowing the type gave you the `Enumerator`. Often this can be emulated on the  index but not always.

Comment: @jparthj There is a conversation option in the comments, using a dynamically created chat room.

Answer (score 0):

The foreach loop has a slightly different purpose. It is meant for itterating through some collection that implements IEnumerable. It's performance is much slower.

for the reference you can see

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6759/FOREACH-Vs-FOR-C

Comment: It depends on implementation, often but not always true